# Implement persistence message queue using plain file in Linux

Tags: c, linux

Here i want to implement persistence queue in C programming.
Here i want save messages to persistence queue and then i want to send them.
If my embedded device restarts and when starts again then and then i can also send messages from persistence message queue which are pending.

Can any one have some idea how i can implement this and how it will works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Store it on some persistent storage.

There's not much more to tell you with the information you provided.

Comment: I can do this things using some plain file storage?

Comment: @user1089679 What else would you want to use? Of course if you need some sort of transaction logic and you don't want to implement that yourself, you can grab some simple database.

Comment: Database in C how i can Inlcude database in C program. i can do with file. not sqllite.

Comment: @user1089679 You choose a library and use it. And sqlite is one of those libraries that use a single file for storing the database. But again, this is only if you need transactions, which I'm guessing you don't really need.

Comment: No i dnt want transactions really need i just want to save messages in file and send them to destinations after getting response i have to remove that messages from the file. if i am getting ACK response from the destination otherwise i cant delete that messages.

Comment: @user1089679 Well yes, then you will be fine with a simple file (or files).

Comment: thanks a lot for Help can u please suggest me way how can i achieve this thing. I have to make any queue logic in code or i have to manage messages in fine other way?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15269/discussion-between-let-me-be-and-user1089679)

Comment: Here i have one Utility to make some things on embedded device. this utility is sent messages to destination. as of now i use simple queue for sending messages. but i want to send messages which are in queue after device reboots this cant happen in simple queue which i developed pragmatically, that's why i need persistence queue for save and remove messages after sent them to destination.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be persistent than you have to store data on hard drive. What I would suggest is using http://www.sqlite.org/ for it. There are bindigs for many languages.

Answer (score 0):

A persistent message is a message that must not be lost, even if the broker fails.

A persistent queue is able to write messages to disk, so that they will not be lost in the event of system shut down or failure.

Now, messages can be either persistent or non-persistent that travel through the persistent queues.

When a sender sends a persistent message to the broker, it routes it to the recipient queue and waits for the message to be written to the persistent store, before acknowledging delivery to the actual sender. 
If a queue is not persistent, messages on the queue are not written to disk.
If a message is not persistent, it is not written to disk even if it is on a persistent queue.

When a reciever queue reads a message from a persistent queue, it is not removed from the queue until the reciever acknowledges the message.

Now you have to put in a journaling mechanism, to keep record of the states of the messages and the brokers on the disk.Then you have to manage caches for the messages and the journals, in a proper order.

This is a simple idea of what a persistent queue is supposed to be and how to write one.
Persistent queues are used by many proprietary software systems like the IBM WebSphere, RedHat's MRG,etc. Refer them for more idea.